Accessing public assets via server action nextjs
I'm working on a Next.js 14 application where I need to use images stored in the public folder. While the images load correctly on the client side, I encounter issues when trying to read an image file from the public folder within a server action. I am new to nextjs and may oversee something obvious here...
Project Setup

Next.js Version: 14 Hosting Platform:
Vercel UI library: MUI Image
Locations:

/public/LandingPageImage.png (used in a component and
loads fine)
/public/Icon.png (fails to load in a server action)



Client-side Code (Working)
The following code correctly loads LandingPageImage.png on the landing page:
<Box
  component="img"
  sx={{
    position: "absolute",
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%",
    objectFit: "cover",
  }}
  alt="alt"
  src="/LandingPageImage.png"
/>

Server-side Code (Not Working when deployed on Vercel, working locally)
  console.log(fs.readdirSync("./"));
  const image = new ImageRun({
    data: fs.readFileSync("./Public/Icon.png"),
    transformation: {
      width: 140,
      height: 50,
    },
  });

I noticed that also on development locally, I am not allowed to use the next shortcut of referencing the static serverd files in the public folder by using "/" as path. Therefore, when using fs I had to write it as "./Public/Icon.png" which works locally in development.
Vercel logs
From the vercel logs I can see that the file is not found:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './Public/Icon.png'
    at Object.openSync (node:fs:573:18)
    at Object.readFileSync (node:fs:452:35)
    at w (/var/task/.next/server/app/workflow/[projectId]/[protocolId]/page.js:1:25191)
    at c (/var/task/.next/server/app/workflow/[projectId]/[protocolId]/page.js:1:26376)
    at async a (/var/task/.next/server/app/workflow/[projectId]/[protocolId]/page.js:1:23033)
    at async /var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:16:418
    at async rP (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:15:7978)
    at async r5 (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:18:1139)
    at async es (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:16:26320)
    at async ei.responseCache.get.routeKind (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/server.runtime.prod.js:17:1026) {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: './Public/Icon.png',
  digest: '3899936968'
}

Debugging attempts
Accordingly, I added some console statements to understand the folder structure better:
console.log("./ ", fs.readdirSync("./"));
console.log("/ ", fs.readdirSync("/"));
console.log("../ ", fs.readdirSync("../"));
console.log("../../ ", fs.readdirSync("../../"));

Which resulted in:
../../  ['THIRD-PARTY-LICENSES.txt', 'bin', 'boot', 'dev', 'etc', 'home', 'lambda-entrypoint.sh', 'lib', 'lib64', 'local', 'media', 'mnt', 'opt', 'proc', 'root', 'run', 'sbin', 'srv', 'sys', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var']
../  ['adm', 'cache', 'db', 'empty', 'ftp', 'games', 'kerberos', 'lang', 'lib', 'local', 'lock', 'log', 'mail', 'nis', 'opt', 'preserve', 'rapid', 'run', 'runtime', 'spool', 'task', 'telemetry', 'tmp', 'tracer', 'yp']
/  ['THIRD-PARTY-LICENSES.txt', 'bin', 'boot', 'dev', 'etc', 'home', 'lambda-entrypoint.sh', 'lib', 'lib64', 'local', 'media', 'mnt', 'opt', 'proc', 'root', 'run', 'sbin', 'srv', 'sys', 'tmp', 'usr', 'var']
./  ['.next', '___next_launcher.cjs', 'node_modules', 'package.json']

No Public folder? Is it somehwere in .next?
Final Comments
So basically, the assets within the Public folder are accessible from the client side, but when trying to get them with a Server Action via fs it seems that the Public folder does not exist at all. At least on the server side.
Do I have to store assets for the server differently with nextjs?
Potential Solutions
I read about the option to create a designated API for the image so the server action can call that endpoint to get the image. Alternatively, the image could be fetched from "https://myapp.vercel.app/Icon.png". Both solutions feel a bit patchwork and I would have assumed that this scenario is somewhere covered by Nextjs.

Have you tried this way?
const dir = path.join(process.cwd(), "path_which_you_want");
const content = fs.readFileSync(dir);

